# GAE Full Text Search, querying multi-valued fields

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

For a document structure with a multi-valued field (that is multiple fields with the same name), is there a way to match one field at a time?

example for further explanation:
given the following "Store" document with multi-valued text field "Product",

Name   | Product   | Product     | Product

store1 | red shirt | blue shorts | green hat

trying to run this query: Product=(red AND hat) ,retrieves "store1"!!
is there a way to fix this behavior? (i.e. only return documents with "red" and "hat" in the same Product field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with a single document. You will have to create a document for every "Product" and link those to the document with the "Name" document (or even directly to the database).

Comment: looks like I got no other options

Answer (score 0):

You should store the products as [Atom fields](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_atom_fields) so you match with ONLY that exact same value.

Comment: that's not the issue, I still want to text-search fields (i.e. substrings) but the problem is GAE treats fields with the same name as if they're one big field, that means it matches a value from one field AND another value from another field with the same name (i.e. a record with product="red shirt", product="green hat" matches the query product=(red AND hat))